# Directory search not working on Eduma theme

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming, add-on

The search form in the user directory from Paid Membership Pro doesn't work if Eduma theme is activated.

The form is not even sending the POST request when I enter or click the search icon. It works just fine using Twenty Twenty Four theme, but I need it working in Eduma.